# Are entity types different than keys?

Tags: database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, data-modeling

Do entity types/kinds have any special property or restriction compared to a Key? It seems to me that the entity type is just a key except it has no parent and the API clients use this concept to avoid collisions but technically there is no difference at the datastore level. It's all a big key. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** *Yes, Entity Kind is different from the Key in that it is used for indexing purposes. Think of it as roughly analogous to a table name.*

By entity type, I'm assuming you are referring to Entity Kind.

The Key of an entity is globally unique to your project, it is composed from the Entity Kind, its Id or Name, and optionally an ancestor path (which is more Kind and Id/Name pairs).

In the simplistic cases, you can think of a 'Kind' as a table name. Cloud Datastore automatically indexes every Entity by its Kind, which allows you to do 'global' queries for Entities of that Kind - regardless of whether they are a root Entity of the descendant of another entity.